# In angular 2+ how do I communicate between sibling components

Tags: angular

I have 3 components I want them to interact with each other.

Tried with services it is not not solving my problem. Need help on it

Comment: Its elborated here, can go through it https://angularfirebase.com/lessons/sharing-data-between-angular-components-four-methods/

Answer (score 0):

Try using rxjs Subject approach for it. If the components are in different pages try using ngrx store state management

Comment: Can you please elaborate on it